# Axios not sending basic authorization

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, axios

In a VueJS app I am making an axios call to an API on a remote server. The server is set up to return the correct CORS headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin, and Access-Control-Allow-Headers). It looks like the auth headers are not sent at all.

Here is the pertinent code:

```
var config = "auth: {username: 'username', password: 'secret'},
              headers: {accept: 'application/json'}";                                                               
axios.get(self.link, config)                                                                                                                                         
     .then(function (response) {                                                                                                                                      
     self.jobDetails = response.data;                                                                                                                             
     console.log(response.data);                                                                                                                                  
     })                                                                                                                                                               
     .catch(function (error) {                                                                                                                                        
          console.log(error);                                                                                                                                          
     });
```

The accept header is sent correctly. The auth header is not sent at all. So, I get a 401.

All searches for an answer point to CORS solutions. But, I do not get the CORS preflight error. So, I think the ORIGIN request is handled correctly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

TIA

**EDIT**
The Response header does include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. The server appears to be responding correctly.

Comment: are you supposed to be sending the config as a string?

Comment: @Jeff I am not sure...followed an example. accept header does work, though

Comment: @Jeff For giggles, I tried sending the config as a js object, and I get the CORS preflight error

Comment: I think that's a server issue. I've never seen anything sent as a string like that before so I'm almost positive you made the right change and now you're having an issue with the server not sending back the right headers